# How do I copy rows from one MySQL table to another and update one of the values based on a variable

Tags: php, mysql, copy

How do I loop through all the rows of a MySQL table and copy all its content to another table and at the same time copy some of the rows multiple times and update one of it values (time) to days later. The days later will be based on another value in the table.
Table a holdsthe data that should be copied. If the next_event is '0' it's only added once. If the next_event is 604800 (which should be equal to one week) the the row should be added multipe times with the next_event value added to the date. In the example below I've added event1 and event3 3 times.

Table a:

```
name        date             time        event       next_event

name1       2012-06-02       18:00:00    event1      604800
name1       2012-06-02       19:00:00    event2      0
name1       2012-06-02       20:00:00    event3      604800
name1       2012-06-02       21:00:00    event4      0
```

Table b:

```
name        date             time        event       next_event

name1       2012-06-02       18:00:00    event1      604800
name1       2012-06-02       19:00:00    event2      
name1       2012-06-02       20:00:00    event3      604800
name1       2012-06-02       21:00:00    event4     
name1       2012-13-02       18:00:00    event1      604800
name1       2012-13-02       20:00:00    event3      604800
name1       2012-20-02       18:00:00    event1      604800
name1       2012-20-02       20:00:00    event3      604800
```

Hope this makes more sence.
Thanks.

Comment: nope this makes no sense, what make sense is you post both the table information (screenshot will be helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the records with [mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).
Use an [if-statement](http://se.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) to check whatever you have to check (doing multiple copies etc).
Use [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to issue INSERT or UPDATE directives to target table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subselects, but at some point it gets difficult to keep track and you may find it better to combine with php-code (or make a stored proc that uses a cursor)

> insert into B b2 (col1,col2,col3) values  (select
>   a1.col1,a1.col2,(select a2.col3 + (select the day-delay here ...) 
>   from A a2 where some-criteria)  from A a1 where some-other-criteria)

If your table is very large you may get better performance if coding everything in SQL.